# Propagator $K_F(x-x)$ in Feynman diagrams

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

Sorry for the elemental question, but this is a doubt that just struck me. I'm currently learning Feynman diagrams for different interacting theories (course bibliography is mostly Peskin and Greiner), and I came across this interrogative (questioning).

In particular, when deducing the Feynman rules for a certain theory using the Wick theorem, we take different combinations for the contractions of the field, which thus are traduced in Feynman propagators (for simplicity, consider scalar fields):

$$K_F(x-y)$$

When we contract a field with itself, the propagator is obviously given by:

$$K_F(x-x)$$

My question is, why does the propagator of $K_F(x-x)=K_F(0)$ not equal zero? I ask this because intuition says that, if the particle doesn't propagate, the propagator should be zero, but if we recall the expression of the Feynman propagator:

$$K_F(x-y)=\int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{E_p}}(e^{-ip\cdot x}\hat{a}_p+e^{ip\cdot x}\hat{a}^\dagger_p)$$

It's clear from the mathematics that non-zero is for $x=y$. Moreover, I saw that they can actually write the diagrams of $K_F(x-x)$ as vacuum bubbles.

Comment: Recall? [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator#Feynman_propagator). In QFT it is a Green's function, not a kernel.

Comment: Well from that point of view, since it's a Green function it's non-zero when the argument is zero. What I find strange, however, is that just before I studied the Feynman propagator I studied the propagator $\langle x_1|x_1\rangle$ that later turned out to be part of the Feynman propagator, and since it was effectively described as a kernel I thought it was zero when $x_1=x_2$.

Comment: No; the covariant object is the identity at coincidence. A δ-function.

Comment: You're right, I was forgetting the temporal ordering which includes the step functions, so effectively it becomes a delta function. Thank you.